# What Visual Studio Component contains the Public Assemblies?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, docker

I have a Windows Forms project in Visual Studio 17 that uses `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll`, which is located in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` folder.

In the `.csproj` file (csproj 2015 format), the reference is listed as follows:

```xml
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

(If I switch to the `.csproj` version 2017, and even the reference remains the same, the project does not compile even locally.)

I'm trying to compile the project inside Docker, but it does not find the DLL.
What component of Visual Studio should I install to get this DLL as well?

Comment: what type of project are you building?

Comment: I try to build a Windows Form project.

Comment: That's a Visual Studio component which is usually only used by VS extensions. Why do you need it in a WinForms app and within Docker?

Comment: It is a legacy project in my company. I guess it shows complex graphs built in our code. It's an internal tool.

Comment: have you installed the visual studio sdk in your container?

Comment: @DanielA.White Did you mean this part? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2017#visual-studio-extension-development

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the reference, you can set the `Copy Local` option to true, in order to have the specified assembly copied to the target "bin" directory. The assembly loader searches the dlls in the same folder of the executing assembly, and only later in the GAC (the process is more involved than this, but this should suffice for your purposes).